# Haskell Windows hPutStrLn doesn't block on network handle

Tags: multithreading, haskell, network-programming

Note: I'm running in windows (though I'd like to be as cross-platform as possible in my approaches to problems like this)

I understand how it's a good thing that it doesn't block, but in my particular case I want it to block, is there any trick for causing it to block, or is there a better approach to what I'm doing right here:

```
hPutStrLn hdl "bye\n"
hClose hdl
```

Problem is, the `hClose` get's called before the full "bye\n" is sent over the line, on the other end of the network it just gets "b" or "by" and then the `hClose` kills the connection.

So, how do I go about ensuring I sent the full "bye\n" across the wire before `hClose` cuts the line?

Do I just use a sleep for a quick moment and accept the imperfection of the solution?

Comment: Does an `hFlush hdl` make a difference?

Comment: @DanielFischer works, thanks! I was presuming the Ln version of output functions would flush automatically. Though, is this passing now just because the flush gives it an extra moment before close is called, or because it actually wasn't flushed previously?

Comment: The latter. Most consoles are line buffered by default, so it would work without the flush, but that isn't necessarily true for other handles. I was under the impression that hClose performs a flush on the handle though, apparently that's not the case.

Comment: Closing a handle doesn't flush it? Seriously?? o_O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is in comments above from @DanielFischer, just posting here for the next person who wonders since he didn't feel inclined to write the answer.

Needs an hFlush hdl.

I was presuming the Ln version of output functions would flush automatically. Most consoles are line buffered in which case this is true, but not all. Also worth noting hClose doesn't perform a flush before closing.